# Making Timer (swift) without NSTimer

Tags: swift

Is it possible to make a timer in Xcode 6 without using a NSTimer? By this I mean you can specify a time increment to repeat a certain amount of code? Or to add on is it possible to make a NSTimer that isn't has a selector selecting a different method just continues the code inside the same method the NSTimer is implement in?

Comment: "Is it possible?" questions always have three potential answers: "Yes, it is possible", "No, it's not possible", and "Maybe, depending on what you mean precisely". Which of those three answers will you accept as correct and helpful? If the answer is "None of the above", then you need to restate your question to be more specific than "Is it possible?", and you should [edit] to do so. (If one of them is in fact what you want, let me know and I'll post it as an answer instead so you can accept.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to build a scenario as described in your post. Following code shows the basic idea of what I would do to simulate a timer without NSTimer. Note, by default, the code is using NSThread, alternatively you may set useGCD true to dispatch using GCD.

```
class Timer: NSObject {

    var interval = 1.0 // Interval at 1.0 second
    var useGCD = false // Set true to use GCD

    var _isTimerRunning = false

    func start() {
        if !_isTimerRunning {
            if !useGCD {
                var thread = NSThread(target: self, selector: Selector("timerFunction"), object: nil)
                thread.start()
            } else {
                var queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.threading", nil)
                dispatch_async(queue, {
                    self.timerFunction()
                })
            }
            _isTimerRunning = true
        }
    }

    func stop() {
        _isTimerRunning = false
    }

    func timerFunction() {
        while (_isTimerRunning) {
            /*
             * TO-DO Designated code goes here
             */
            NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(interval) // Interrupt
        }
    }
}
```

Start timer:

```
var timer = Timer()
timer.start()
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a delay function? Set inside a loop to fire repeatedly.

```
delay (5.0) {

//code to execute here

}

func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
        dispatch_after(
            dispatch_time(
                DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
            ),
            dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure! I have an objective-c macro I made for this purpose that will likely port to swift in some way or another.

```
#define startBlockTimer(delayInSeconds, block) {\
__block float runTime = (-1.0f*delayInSeconds);\
__block BOOL keepRunning = YES;\
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{ for(;keepRunning&&(runTime+=delayInSeconds);[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:delayInSeconds]) {dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block );}});\
}
#define blockTimerRunTime runTime
#define stopBlockTimer() keepRunning = NO;
```

---

Used like this:

```
startBlockTimer(0.5, ^{

        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:arc4random_uniform(1000)/1000.0f saturation:0.75f brightness:0.75f alpha:1.0f];

        if (blockTimerRunTime > 5.0f) {
            stopBlockTimer();
        }

    });
```